# getting the words before a specific String value

Tags: java

I asked a question about the following method a while ago and came up with quite different question. Suppose I have String `A B -> C` or `A B -> carry sum` or `X Y Cin -> Cout Sum`. How can I extract the words before `->` without including `->`? And then extracting the words after `->`?

```
public void parseContactsLine(String line)
    {
        String[] words = line.split("->");

        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems like you already have it figured out, no? `String[] words = line.split("->");` is storing it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first split for "->" will separate into two strings the list of words of each side.

Then you can re-split by spaces using `.split("\\s");` to get a list of each words.

You would end up with

```
String[] wordsAfterLambda = line.split("->")[1].split("\\s");
for(String s : wordsAfterLambda)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Notice that I used a `for-each` instead of `for` which I tend to prefer when there is no need to keep the index.

---

Edit

As per your comment, the `[1]` is to access the array value and not linked to the split itself, it is the same as doing

```
String[] words = line.split("->");
String[] wordsAfterLambda = words[1].split("\\s");
```

Comment: What does [1] mean in split?

Comment: @Nikolay the first split return an array, so I retrieve the second value using `[1]`.

Comment: @Nikolay split take the delimiter as argument, here we want to retrieve from each side of "->"  so we give it as delimiter. Then we retrieve the part to the right with `[1]` and re split it with spaces as delimiter to retrieve an array containing each words.

Comment: I wanted to say why there is "test" ??

Comment: @Nikolay Oops, it's a typo.. It should be "line" instead.. Edited.